# C++: OpenGL orthographic depth

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-buffer

I've ran into a problem that is killing me. I'm building a 2D game (with orthographic projection, all math is done with glm) and I'm using a renderer that draws prmitives in one call (through element-arrays). This posses a problem as things are drawn in the order given and that's not what I want. I've tried using a z-coordinate to do depth testing. When I enable depth testing it still doesn't draw them in the right order but instead the opposite way where the first given to the renderer are on top, the rest follow behind it.

Here's some code:

```
// Vertex Shader
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;
uniform mat4 camera_matrix;
out vec4 fragment_color;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = camera_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    fragment_color = color;
{

// Fragment Shader
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;
in vec4 fragment_color;
void main()
{
    color = fragment_color;
}

// Part of the rendering code
void render()
{
    window.clear();
    shader_program.begin();
    renderer.drawRectangle(vec2(0, 0),
                           vec2(100, 100),
                           vec4(1, 0, 0, 1),
                           1.0f); // depth value
    renderer.drawRectangle(vec2(50, 50),
                           vec2(100, 100),
                           vec4(0, 1, 0, 1),
                           -1.0f); // depth value
    shader_program.end();
    window.refresh();
}

// Renderer's code
void drawPolygon(const vec2* vertices, int count, const vec4& color, float depth)
{ // The drawRectangle just creates 4 vertices of the corners and passes them to this function
    int first = m_offset;
    m_vertices.emplace_back(vec3(vertices[0], depth), color);
    m_vertices.emplace_back(vec3(vertices[1], depth), color);
    m_offset += 2;
    for (int i = 2; i < count; i++)
    {
        m_vertices.emplace_back(vec3(vertices[i], depth), color);
        // Basically a triangle fan
        m_indices.emplace_back(first);
        m_indices.emplace_back(m_offset[1] - 1);
        m_indices.emplace_back(m_offset[1]++);
    }
}

// Draw call
void flush()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * m_vertices.size(), m_vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * m_indices.size(), m_indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ibo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Update January 6, 2016:
After thinking more about the issue I've assume it might be the window API I'm using (GLFW) so I changed my window class to adapt SDL2 (which was easy, go modular code) and the problem still persists so it's down to my code.

Comment: What's the value of `camera_matrix`?

Comment: @Reto Koradi The camera_matrix was created with glm::ortho(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, -1.0f, 1.0);

Comment: At least with the rectangles shown here, the first being drawn on top looks correct, since its depth is smaller. Or is it always the first one, even if you swap the order of the draw calls? That would be odd.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Swapping the order of the draws changes who's in front.

Comment: One possible problem is that you don't have a depth buffer. How you request that depends on the framework/toolkit you use to set up your OpenGL drawing, but it typically happens around the time you create the context.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after looking into the problem more I forgot you could "debug" shaders by checking values and outputing a certain color if a condition was met. So I changed both my shaders to pass the posititon to the fragment and tested the built-in variable gl_FragDepth as well and found it to not be set (which is obvious although I assumed this was set automatically, correct me if I'm wrong). When setting that value with the z-coord this whole problem was fixed.
Here's the updated shaders:

```
// Vertex Shader
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

uniform mat4 camera_matrix = mat4(1.0);

out DATA
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
} fragment_out;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = camera_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    fragment_out.position = position;
    fragment_out.color = color;
}

//Fragment Shader
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

in DATA
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
} fragment_in;

void main()
{
    gl_FragDepth = fragment_in.position.z;
    color.rgb = fragment_in.color;
}
```

Now I can resume this project

Comment: Please fix me if I am wrong.   The bug is in `gl_Position=`, it should be `ProjectionMatrix × ViewMatrix × ModelMatrix × v` , and  "I assumed this was set automatically" is correct. (reference : https://learnwebgl.brown37.net/12_shader_language/glsl_builtin_functions.html )

Answer (score 1):

I would put this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation. Have you used the code
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
earlier in your program? Without this, whatever is drawn last will be on top.

Comment: It says in the question that the OP enabled depth testing.